# Edit HTML ID value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to make a 'Little Critters' game for a project.
I've recently discovered the beauty that is the `<meter>` and decided to use that for my 'health' and 'happiness' bars.

**HTML**

```
<meter low=".5" optimum=".8" high=".7" id="health" value="0.1"></meter>
<button type="button" id="feedme">Feed Me</button>
```

**JS**

```
var health = document.getElementById("health")
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#feedme').click(function(){
        if (health === 1) {
            confirm("I'm already full!");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('health').setAttribute('value', + 0.5);
            confirm("Ewww, I really hate brussel sprouts");
        }      
        if (health > 1) {
            health = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

The above code changes the 'health' ID to 0.5 instead of adding 0.5. I believe this is because I'm using `.setAttribute()` instead of something else.

I've tried a couple of different ways including `health.value = food;` (increasing the var food instead of the meter) and other, more lengthy solutions that I can't link here due to insufficient reputation

So, what can I use in place of `.setAttribute()` to *modify* the value instead of *setting* it?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4dgnyjs/1/)

Comment: You do have to take `setAttribute()`, but in before you have to cache the attribute by `getAttribute()`, to add `0.5` to it!

Comment: Sorry if I'm busting your bubble but meter is not supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter

Comment: @DOCASAREL would that be in a separate line of code?

Comment: @user1477388 I know, but I only use Chrome and this project is just to be shown to my teacher next time she's on site (so she'll view it on my PC), so that's not an issue :) thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, something that makes it at least work in term of meter ( except on IE ). The `UX` of your game is certainly defined by you %)P.

The `unary plus operator`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B).

```
var health = document.getElementById("health")
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#feedme').click(function(){
        var val = + document.getElementById('health').getAttribute('value') //unary + to Integer

        if (val > 1) {
            val = 1;
        }

        if (val === 1) {
            confirm("I'm already full!");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('health').setAttribute('value', val + 0.5);
            confirm("Ewww, I really hate brussel sprouts");
        }      

    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4dgnyjs/4/).

Comment: that works great, thanks. Just one question, I noticed that the `confirm("I'm already full!");` didn't flash up once it hit 1, but the `confirm("Ewww, I really hate brussel sprouts");` flashed up every time (once I removed the commenting) why's that?

Comment: I thought you want to have the user feel, that he was feed with nice live-giving "Brussel Sprouts", but that he didn't like it. %)P So I removed the comment now in the answer too. But other than that, well I did not know on first view, what you want to do either?!? It is in the `else` with `setAttribute()` and so the technical uppopping is correct...! Where do you want to have it?

Comment: I mean `confirm("I'm already full!");` should run when val === 1, but it's not, and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Thing is, it works ( click once more ), but it is read before **`setAttribute()`** and got the old value...hmm. Seems you got to put some more logic into your game. ;) BTW, this is all *non-jQuery*!

Comment: "Brussels" sprouts :)